# Docker settings stored after removing container

Tags: docker, seafile-server

I'm using a seafile container on my raspberry pi 2.

When running:

```
install -dm777 $HOME/seafile &&
docker run --name seafile \
  -v $HOME/seafile:/home/seafile \
  -p 143.93.44.14:8000:8000 \
  -p 143.93.44.14:8082:8082 \
  -ti yangxuan8282/rpi-alpine-seafile
```

I'm asked to set the admin user.

After removing the container and images and rerunning the command, I'm not asked to set the user and I can't set a new one.

So my question is, where are settings stored if the docker container is removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete the files in:

```
$HOME/seafile
```

and then re-create you contianer

Comment: I did so, but  still no setup appears after recreating the container.

Comment: `docker rm -f seafile && docker system prune -f` and then recreate it

Comment: `docker rm -f seafile && docker rmi yangxuan8282/rpi-alpine-seafile  docker system prune -f ` and delete files in `$HOME/seafile`

Comment: Okay, after rerunning it several times, it finally worked. :)